# What is a homogeneous and isotropic frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I have heard that inertial frames of reference in the context of special relativity are both isotropic and homogeneous. I know what isotropic and homogeneous mean in a general context, but what do they mean when relating to a frame of reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply application of the general context to the specific case of frames of reference.

A **homogeneous** frame of reference has the same physical laws regardless of location within the frame.

an **isotropic** frame of reference has the same physical laws regardless of which direction you look in the frame.

Comment: just a clarification, if I say certain x-y frame is inertial implies that physics should hold same at r and r' measure from inertial x-y frame. But isotropic means the no matter which direction I look at, the physics still remains same, but since we have fixed the origin, for a given r, there exist only direction, could you explain this?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're getting mixed up between special relativity and general relativity.

We wouldn't normally describe an inertial frame as *isotropic and homogeneous*, but in GR there exists a frame in which the matter scattered around the universe looks (approximately) isotropic and homogeneous. This is the [comoving frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance).